# How to parse Nth occurence of a string and get the text in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find the 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th strings after a separator.

For example I need to parse strings that may look like the following:

```
1
1.2
1.2.3
1.2.3.4
1.10.1.10
```

Expected results would be:

```
1,NULL,NULL,NULL
1,2,NULL,NULL
1,2,3,NULL
1,2,3,4
1,10,1,10
```

This is on Microsoft SQL 2008 R2.

Thanks!

Comment: 2008 (R2) ran *completely* out of support **4 years** ago. It is *long* past time you upgraded by now; using such an outdated version, that has received no security updates and has known vulnerabilities, is a significant and avoidable risk. *Not to mention this is* far *easier on recent versions*.

Comment: Totally agree with you Thom. This is actually for a data extract as we migrate to a new system.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: *"This is actually for a data extract as we migrate to a new system."* Then why not fix the problem and normalise the data too?

Comment: `parsename`....

Comment: @SalmanA i think the problem with parsename is that it returns stuff in the wrong order for this task :/

Comment: You can do something like this: https://dbfiddle.uk/hcFvpssP I think XML should be supported in 2008